# Vue Routing Lifecycle

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have a Vue app which contains some admin-protected portions. I am able to refresh and stay on any non-admin-protected URL, but for the ones defined in the router as requiring an admin user type, whenever I refresh it redirects to the login screen, though I can then re-navigate to the backend without actually logging in again. I can see by logging that the router is checking the store's state and performing the redirect, before the store is initialized. Is there a way to set the order of events, or will I need to rely on something like localStorage rather than the store's state to determine if a user is authorized to view a page?

```
{ path: '/admin', component: AdminDash,
    beforeEnter (to, from, next) {
      if (store.state.isAdmin) {
        console.log('store.state.isAdmin 1a', store.state.isAdmin)
        next()
      } else {
        console.log('store.state.isAdmin 1b', store.state.isAdmin)
        next('/signin')
      }
    }
  }
```

The else clause fires on refreshing the page, which is undesirable.

Comment: you will need to rely on something like `localStorage` if you want to persist the state of the user

Comment: But don't store `isAdmin` in `localStorage`, since the user could edit `localStorage` themselves.

Comment: Thank you. Any thoughts on how this is normally done?